# Using NHibernate IPreInsertEventListener and trying to find the mapped table

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm attempting to implement a PreInsertEvent listener using the latest version (which was at the time of the writing: 2.1.2.4000) of NHibernate.  One of the things I want to do with in this listener is find the database table that my entity is going to be mapped too. (Assuming that it is only one table).

Does anyone know where in the IEntityPersister I might be able to find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is on the PreInsertEvent.  Persister.PropertySpaces

```
public bool OnPreInsert(PreInsertEvent evt) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < evt.Persister.PropertySpaces.Length; i++)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("\tevt.Persister.PropertySpaces = {0}", evt.Persister.PropertySpaces[i]);
  }
}
```

From the code base:
    // Returns an array of objects that identify spaces in which properties of
    // this entity are persisted, for instances of this class only.
    // For most implementations, this returns the complete set of table names
    // to which instances of the mapped entity are persisted (not accounting
    // for superclass entity mappings).